# If one checkbox is selected, automatically select the rest on page jQuery?

Tags: jquery

If the checkbox with the class "selectAll" is checked I want the rest of the checkboxes on the page to automatically be checked. I got this working with the following:

```
$('.selectAll').click(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', true);
});
```

But I want all checkboxes to be unchecked when select all is clicked again, I can't get that part working. How can that be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change `true` to other parameters...

```
$('.selectAll').click(function() {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

(Test: http://jsbin.com/ogobi5)